# Strange behavior of new Array vs [ ] in JS

Tags: javascript

```js
const foo = new Array(2) // [<empty>, <empty>]
            .fill(new Array(2)) // [[<empty>, <empty>], [<empty>, <empty>]]
            .map((subArr) => subArr.fill(0)); // [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

const result = foo.map((subArr, index) => {
  subArr.splice(index, 1, 1);
  return subArr; 
});

console.log(result) // [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

But the result is different in a similar case:

```js
const foo = [[0, 0], [0, 0]];

const result = foo.map((subArr, index) => {
  subArr.splice(index, 1, 1);
  return subArr;
});

console.log(result); // [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

I do not understand what is the reason for such a difference, because in both cases I work with an array `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`

I expect the same result in both cases

Comment: `.fill(new Array(2))` here you assign each element the same array. Remember that arrays are objects in JavaScript, and you can see objects as references

Comment: The first code is equivalent to `const arr = new Array(2); foo[0] = arr; foo[1] = arr;`.

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much. It took me a lot of time

Comment: BTW, this isn't a difference between `new Array()` and `[]`, it's about `.fill()`. You would have the same problem if you used `.fill([0, 0])`.